# Template factory giving linker error and ignoring reference type

Tags: c++, templates, linker

I am creating a template factory for my project, everything was working fine until I need to add an extra parameter to the object creation process.

The factory has two main templates:

```
template <typename T>
class GenericFactory_c: boost::noncopyable
{
    public:
          typedef typename T::ObjectType_t ObjectType_t;

          //basic creating with just 1 parameter (object name)
          ObjectType_t Create(const String_c &className, const String_c &name) const
          {
              typename ObjectCreatorSet_t::const_iterator it = setObjectCreators.find(className, ObjectCreatorComp_s<T>());
              if(it == setObjectCreators.end())
                   PH_RAISE(OBJECT_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION, "[EntityFactory_c::Create]", name);

              return it->Create(name);
          }

          //"advanced" creation using an additional Y parameter
          template <typename Y>
          ObjectType_t Create(const String_c &className, const String_c &name, Y param) const
          {
              typename ObjectCreatorSet_t::const_iterator it = setObjectCreators.find(className, ObjectCreatorComp_s<T>());
              if(it == setObjectCreators.end())
                  PH_RAISE(OBJECT_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION, "[EntityFactory_c::Create]", name);

              return it->Create(name, param);
          }

          //rest of the code, probably irrelavent to the problem removed for clarity
};
```

The idea is that for certain types, only the create with 2 parameters will be used, for other types only the create with 3 parameters will be used.

That means that for a certain Factory instantiation, never both versions will be used, just one.

For being able to auto register types using static variables, I created a ObjectCreator class, this is defined as follows:

```
template <typename T, typename Y>
class ObjectCreatorBase_c: public ObjectCreatorAutoUnlinkHook_t
{
    public:
         typedef T ObjectType_t;
         typedef Y ObjectCreatorProc_t;

    public:
         ObjectCreatorBase_c(const String_c &name, ObjectCreatorProc_t proc):
             strName(name),
             pfnCreateProc(proc)
         {
         }

         T Create(const String_c &name) const
         {
             return pfnCreateProc(name);
         }

         template <typename Z>
         T Create(const String_c &name, Z param) const
         {
             return pfnCreateProc(name, param);
         }

     //"irrelevant" code removed

         private:
             String_c strName;
             ObjectCreatorProc_t pfnCreateProc;
};
```

And for a EntityComponent type that needs two parameters on construtor (string and Entity reference) I define an object creator as below:

```
template <typename T, typename Y>
class ObjectCreator1_c: public ObjectCreatorBase_c<T, T(*)(const String_c &, Y )>
{       
    public:
        ObjectCreator1_c(const String_c &name, ObjectCreatorProc_t proc):
            ObjectCreatorBase_c(name, proc)             
        {               
            GenericFactory_c<ObjectCreator1_c >::GetInstance().Register(*this);
        }
};
```

And a creator is defined liked this:

```
static ObjectCreator1_c<EntityComponentPtr_t, Entity_c &> CreatorForXYZ_CreatorObject_gl("XYZ", &XYZ::Create);
```

A factory for this is defined like:

```
typedef GenericFactory_c<ObjectCreator1_c<EntityComponentPtr_t, Entity_c &> > EntityComponentFactory_c;
```

And finally, for creating a component I use the code below:

```
Entity_c::CreateCompXYZ()
{
    EntityComponentFactory_c &factory = EntityComponentFactory_c::GetInstance();

    EntityComponentPtr_t xyz = factory.Create("XYZ", "myXYZInstance", *this);
}
```

And finally comes my problem, with the code above, the compiler appears to ignore the reference to the `*this` and tries to create a copy of the Entity object and I get a undefined reference to `Entity_c::Entity_c(const Entity_c &)`, that is ok, because `Entity_c` does not have a copy constructor (non copyable), but the problem is because this code is not expected to try to copy `Entity_c`, but uses it references.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this function

```
Entity_c::CreateCompXYZ()
{
    EntityComponentFactory_c &factory = EntityComponentFactory_c::GetInstance();

    EntityComponentPtr_t xyz = factory.Create("XYZ", "myXYZInstance", *this);
}
```

is actually calling this template for a 3 parameter `Create`

```
//"advanced" creation using an additional Y parameter
template <typename Y>
ObjectType_t Create(const String_c &className, const String_c &name, Y param) const
```

it really **is** trying to copy `Entity_c` (it being `Y` here).

Of course this doesn't work if it is non-copyable!

Comment: Thanks. Actually I re factored this code, made it a bit simpler and fixed the issue, that was really caused by the problem that you spotted.